# Can't Get PyDot to Work in Python 3.5

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip, python-3.5, keras

While using Keras library for machine learning, I keep getting the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "rnn2.py", line 253, in <module>
    from keras.utils.visualize_util import plot
  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda2\envs\py35\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\visualize_util.py", line 13, in <module>
    raise RuntimeError('Failed to import pydot. You must install pydot'
RuntimeError: Failed to import pydot. You must install pydot and graphviz for `pydotprint` to work.
```

My system is Windows 10, Anaconda 3.5 environment. I have tried all of the solutions mentioned in github issues and stack overflow:

like installing pyparsing , pydot-ng, graphviz etc. Nothing is working, I keep getting the error.

What to install to remove the error? Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Do you see the modules you need in `pip3.5 freeze`?

Comment: @chris_anderson i didn't understand, what command to run for checking that?

Comment: Sorry, `pip3.5 freeze` is the command - it produces a list of installed modules for that version of Python, I think.